# Converting local JSP page into global web page without modifying the source code?

Tags: java, javascript, html, web-services, amazon-web-services

I have designed a product recommendation hub using Java and JavaScript in Eclipse. Basic functionality is, if the person enters the product name, it will retrieve the relevant product reviews from the local XAMPP database, perform sentiment analysis on it and dispalys whether the product is recommended or not based on the number of positive or negative sentiments. My questions:

Is it possible to convert this local JSP UI page into a globally accessible web page without modifying my java code?

If Yes, please guide me. If No, please justify to get a clear understanding.

Is it possible using Amazon AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the page via ajax/jquery.

In the target page, create a div tag that will be your placeholder:

```
<div id="myPlaceholder"></div>
```

and add some javascript like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
     $.get("/theurlofthecurrentpage?some=thing", function(data) {
         $("#myPlaceholder").html(data);
     });
});
</script>
```

If the JSP control does full postbacks, you may have to update it to handle it clientside. hopefully this helps.

Comment: thanks for the valuable response! I'm running short of time. I'm new to AJAX. Is it too complex to perform this task? Can you provide some reference links? Does it involve extensive coding?

Comment: www.jquery.com to get the library. save the js file in your project somewhere and then add a reference to the script on your page:  
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>